# "invalid map function" when defining a corecursive tree

Tags: isabelle, corecursion

I’m doing my first experiments with `codatatype`, but I’m stuck rather early. I started with this definition of a branching, possibly infinite tree:

```
codatatype (lset: 'a) ltree = Node (lnext : "'a ⇒ 'a ltree option")
```

and some definitions work fine:

```
primcorec lempty :: "'a ltree"
  where "lnext lempty = (λ _ . None)"

primcorec single :: "'a ⇒ 'a ltree"
  where "lnext (single x) = (λ _ . None)(x := Some lempty)"
```

but this does not work:

```
primcorec many :: "'a ⇒ 'a ltree"
  where "lnext (many x) = (λ _ . None)(x := Some (many x))"
```

as I get the error message

```
primcorec error:
  Invalid map function in "[x ↦ many x]"
```

I could work around it by writing

```
primcorec many :: "'a ⇒ 'a ltree"
  where "lnext (many x) = (λ x'. if x' = x then Some (many x) else None)"
```

which makes be believe that `primcorec` needs to “know something about” the function update operator, similar to how `fun` needs `fundef_cong` lemmas and `inductive` needs `mono` lemmas. But what exactly?

Comment: Oh, and where should I have looked to learn more about this myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the codatatype recurses through other type constructors, then `primcorec` expects that the recursive calls are properly nested in the map functions of these type constructors. In the example, the recursion goes through the function type and the option type, whose map functions are `op o` and `map_option`. Consequently, the recursive call to `many` should have the form `op o (map_option many)`. Hence, the following definition works:

```
primcorec many :: "'a ⇒ 'a ltree"
where "lnext (many x) = map_option many ∘ [x ↦ x]"
```

For convenience, `primcorec` supports a few more syntactic input formats. In particular, the map function for the function type can be also written using lambda abstractions. Additionally, it supports case distinctions and `if`s. This is why your second version is accepted. However, when you look at the generated definition `many_def`, you will see that it is more complicated than with the explicit map functions.

`primcorec` does not suport registration of arbitrary functions, so you cannot use `fun_upd` in the original form. Primitive corecursion is syntactical. Maybe in the future there will be a corecursive counterpart to `function`.

The map functions are explained in the [tutorial on datatypes](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/datatypes.pdf) and in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-08970-6_7).

Comment: Thanks, helpful as always!